# Can I programmatically set an objects property in iOS?

Tags: ios, object, properties

Let's say I have an NSObject Variable that has properties such as Variable.x, Variable.y, Variable.z and I want the program to determine which property is assigned a value and then do it? Is it possible to choose that at runtime? Actually the properties will not be known to the method until it asks for them. So x, y, and z, will not always be the properties. It will have a list of properties available, the object name, and the values to apply to those properties. I don't need to create the properties at runtime (although that would be nice) but I need to look at what is available and assign values to them at runtime. Sorry if this is not detailed enough. I'm mostly self taught and don't use the right terminology sometimes. But this site has saved me a lot of time and aggravation in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do all of this using the Objective-C runtime. See the [Objective-C Runtime Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) , especially `class_copyPropertyList`, `class_getProperty`, `objc_setAssociatedObject` and `objc_getAssociatedObject`. (There are a few different ways to accomplish what you want.)

Given that information, you should be able to find sample code and ample discussion on Stack Overflow, so I won't elaborate further.

Comment: Yes, this sounds like what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could do all this with an NSMutableDictionary. No need to create a custom object at all.

Comment: Unless you wanted to use some of the features that come with properties like weak references, KVO, overridden getters, etc.

Comment: ...and you could do any of those things by putting a category on NSMutableDictionary, should you need to.

Comment: Sure, but then you're creating a custom object…